# Swift ios11 NavigationItem SearchBar won't hide completely

Tags: ios, swift, ios11, swift4, uisearchcontroller

Having an issue with adding a search controller to a `navigationItem` in iOS11 / Swift 4.

Basically everything works as expected for the most part, pull down will reveal the search bar and searching works fine. However when trying to hide the search bar by scroll back up... the bar won't hide completely and remains as a thin strip (see below).

I have declared my search controller as follows:

```
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
searchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = ["All", "Samples"]
searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
navigationItem.searchController = searchController
```

Before (scroll down to reveal search bar):

[image]

After (scroll up to hide):

[image]

Comment: This is because it only fully hides the search bar if you scroll down a sufficient amount.

Comment: It looks like the issue happens when there are only a few rows in the table.

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in this [Apple forums thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/88702).

When the value of this `hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling` is true, the search bar is visible only when the scroll position equals the top of your content view, that's in case you are using a UIViewController, which view property is a normal UIView (It is not a subclass of UIScrollView).

Instead, try to use UITableViewController or ScrollView, it should work as expected

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was happening only when there was a small num of items in the table. 
I came to a non-technical, but rather a logical solution to show the search bar only when there are >10 items in the list. There is no need to have search when you have only a few items anyway.

Answer (score -3):

Try to add this

```
self.navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = true
```